# how to differentiate in Firebase between empty data and non existent endpoint

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase has no way of knowing whether the endpoint you requested is empty or you requested a wrong endpoint. There is no difference, since a wrong endpoint is the same as a non existent endpoint and there are no empty nodes in Firebase.

I understand this is by design, since again, Firebase does not hold empty values.

In either case, Firebase returns a snapshot which converts to `null` after doing `snapshot.val()`. When using `snapshot.exists()` the result is also the same [as seen in the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#child).

Since the end result is the same, it can be frustrating not knowing if you are indeed using the wrong endpoint.

Is there a strategy to prevent this confusion other than maintaining good docs and telling the developers to RTFM?